# C# Core and Angular 7. Doesn`t work SiganlR authorization with JWT

Tags: angular, .net-core, signalr

My hub:

```
[Authorize]
public class ChatHub: Hub 
{
    public ChatHub(UserManager<User> userManager, SignInManager<User> signInManager, IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        ...
    }
    public async Task Send(string message, string to)
    {           
        string token = Context.GetHttpContext().Request.Query["access_token"];
    }
}
```

I get token in

> Context.GetHttpContext().Request.Query["access_token"];

when I remove attribure Authorize. But when I add attribure get message unauthorize

Angular:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.hubConnection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
      .withUrl('https://localhost:5001/chat/',
          { accessTokenFactory: () => localStorage.getItem("token") })
      .build();

    this.hubConnection.start().then(() =>
        console.log('Connection started!'))
    .catch(err => console.log('Error while establishing connection :('));

    this.hubConnection.on("Send", (data) => {
    ...
    });
  }

sendMessage(): void {
    this.hubConnection.invoke('Send', this.message, 'user' )
    .then(res => { console.log(res); })
    .catch(err => console.error(err));
}
```

StartUp:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseSignalR(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapHub<ChatHub>("/chat", options =>
        {
            options.ApplicationMaxBufferSize = 64;
            options.TransportMaxBufferSize = 64;
            options.LongPolling.PollTimeout = System.TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
            options.Transports = HttpTransportType.LongPolling | HttpTransportType.WebSockets;
        });
    });
}
```

Why can't I enter in to the controller with attribute?

Comment: Can you show the code where you are validate the jwt token?

Comment: @Darem I don`t validate token. I create token on server and send to client. Then I send message with token but I getting message unauthorize

Comment: Ok but so you have a anwser to your question. With the [Authorize]-Attribute you try to authorize the user but did not validate the token, so how you will authorize the user?

Comment: @Darem At the moment I check a token with debug.

Comment: maybe you have a look at this tutorial https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2018/08/14/aspnet-core-21-jwt-authentication-tutorial-with-example-api